# Ticker doesn't work in background

Tags: c#, background, windows-phone-8.1, dispatcher, background-music

I am working on background music, streaming music from website. I am trying to get info about music every 3 seconds from web, even when the app is closed. Everything is working except my ticker which is not working in background.

This is my code:

```
public sealed class AudioTask : IBackgroundTask
{
     #region Music properties
     private void setTicker()
     {
          AutoResetEvent _refreshWaiter = new AutoResetEvent(true);
          dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
          dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
          dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
          dispatcherTimer.Start();
      }

      private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
      {
          GetInfoAboutMusic();
      }
}
```

Maybe there is something like `DispatcherTime`? What do I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, it is hard to make a proper suggestion.  You should read this aticle on [Background Tasks in Windows Store Apps](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/05/01/background-tasks-in-windows-store-apps.aspx) and others you can find that reference `IBackgroundTask`.

There is also [How to play background music in windows phone 8.1 with xaml and c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152050/how-to-play-background-music-in-windows-phone-8-1-with-xaml-and-c) which has some good info that may get you unblocked.